# use sed to replace 2 variables into one variable place along with a forward slash

Tags: regex, shell, unix, sed

i am trying to replace 2 variables with / in-between 2 variables but its giving sed expression -e error

```
 sed 's/'$presentnetwork'/'$netmask\/$subnet'/g' -i /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf
```

How to put the / and also substitute a variable using sed even if i try to put only one variable it is also not working

```
 sed 's/'$presentnetwork'/'$netmask\/'/g' -i /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf
```

Is it possible to use escape sequence and variable in the same sed command?

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap it with double quotes `"`:

```
sed "s/$presentnetwork/$netmask\//g" -i /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf
#   ^                              ^
```

#### Example:

```
$ cat a.html 
hello
$ a=hello
$ b=good
$ c=bye
$ sed "s/$a/$b\/$c/g" -i a.html 
$ cat a.html 
good/bye
```

Comment: this works fine , but if $a has a content with / then it is getting failed , eg :- a=10.4.5.6/16   . do we need to use some escape sequence here also ? if so then how to use it

Comment: In this case you have to escape the `/`: `a=10.4.5.6\/16`.

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked , i actually splited $c into 2 like $c and $d then i used like this "s/$a\/$b/$c\/$d/g" then it worked .

Comment: Good to read that, @NaggappanRM :) If your question is answered consider marking this or the other answer as accepted. It will help next people entering in the page

Answer (score 1):

`sed` isn't limited to `/` as delimiter, you can also use some other character to make escaping easier (if you know the character can't be part of your variable):

```
 sed "s_$presentnetwork_$netmask/_g" -i /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf
```

Comment: Good one. In this case I prefer `#` as it is easier to see.